# Python:Get the name of a variable

Tags: python

I declare a variable, say:

```
var=33
```

I want to assign to another variable the string 'var', that is , how to get the symbol's name of the value of the variable.

How can I do it ?

---

I reformulate the question.

```
WHITE=0
RED=1
BLACK=2
```

X=2.

I want to assign the value 'BLACK' to a variable, say, Y, taking into account that X=2.

It is hard to formulate exactly this question.

I want to avoid a code like this:

```
color=''
if X==0:
     color='WHITE'
elif X==1:
etc.
```

Is it possible to get the name of the color-variable as a string?

Comment: This can't be done. A variable is just a name you give to a value. A single value can be known under many names, it's impossible to tell which is the "right" one. Besides, how would you get the value of the variable without using its name in the first place?

Comment: Wow the question just turned 90 degrees

Comment: You'd have to look into the inspect module http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html to inspect classes, objects, methods, stack frame, etc.

Comment: millimoose: this can be done in lisp using an assoc list or an obarray. and this can be done even easier if you dispose of closures...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to assign to another variable the string 'var', that is , how to get the symbol's name of a variable.

No, you don't want to do that. Use a dict:

```
mydata = {}
varname = 'var'
mydata[varname] = 33
```

Technically, you could use the `dict` from `globals()` or `locals()` to store this, and it would be available as a "real variable", but really, there's no good reason to do that, it will make your code much more difficult to understand.

The way to avoid the code you give:

```
color=''
if X==0:
     color='WHITE'
elif X==1:
etc.
```

Is with:

```
COLORS = ('WHITE', 'RED', 'BLACK')
x = 2
try:
    color = COLORS[x]
except IndexError:
    color = 'DEFAULT COLOR'
```

This eliminates sequential ifs, and maintenance beyond expanding `COLORS`. You could also do:

```
COLORS = {0: 'WHITE', 1: 'RED', 2: 'BLACK'}
x = 2
color = COLORS.get(x, 'DEFAULT COLOR')
```

But that requires manual management of the indices (keys) also.

Comment: @alinsoar, the _reason_ you don't want to do it is because you can't. In python, variables aren't containers, they're just names that point at things.

Comment: Yes, the solution must be reduced somehow to investigating the environments. My question is : is there a smart way to do it ?

Comment: @alinsoar No, don't mess around with environments, just use dicts (environments are presented to the programmer as dicts in python).

Comment: @alinsoar See my updated answer on how to avoid the code you mention in your updated question.

Answer (score 3):

```
colors = {0:"WHITE", 1:"RED", 2:"BLACK"}
X=2
print colors[X]
```

Comment: Even better: `colors = ["WHITE", "RED", "BLACK"]`. No need for a `dict` when the keys are a prefix of the natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely, positively, MUST have it:

```
x = 2
n = locals()
n['x'] # 2
```

Comment: For the record, this is awful and a terrible idea.

Comment: +1. At the same time, for the record, it can be done :) for quick scripts that you throw away and never look at again (why do these always come back to haunt me?) you might get away with this...

Comment: It's generally easy enough to do things the Right Way in Python that even for quick-and-dirty it's not worth doing things like this.

Comment: Totally agree. In this case I'd argue that the Right Way is easier.